# converting value types of an object to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, reflection

How do I iterate through all the value types of an object and convert that into a Dictionary? I was heading the reflection way

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

but that gives both value types and references types.

Comment: What would be the key (property name?) and value (value serialized to something) in your dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `IsValueType` property of the `PropertyInfo` `Type`:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsValueType)
```

Adding it to a dictionary becomes:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsValueType)) {
    dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj));
}
```

Where the key is the name and the value is the value in the `obj` instance.

Comment: Perhaps you're still busy, but I am missing the Dictionary ;)

Comment: OP didn't say using the dictionary was the issue.. so I didn't include that. Also, I would need more information from the OP as to the exact requirement to include that part.

Comment: True, but for the sake of the title, people that don't understand that part are missing a simple example. Just saying, but while assumption is the mother of all ...., you could easily use the name for example. You already have my vote anyways.

Comment: I have added an example.